# How to find max nesting with recursion js

Tags: javascript, html, recursion

I have a tree of `<div>` elements.

I need to find max nesting of div's with recursion.

I now made it for first div

```js
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var divs = body.children;
var element = divs[0];


count = 0
function recursion (data) {    
    if (data.children.length > 0) {
      count++
        console.log(data.children[0])
        return recursion(data.children[0])
    }
   else {
    console.log(count)
    return count
    }
}


recursion(element);
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help to make it for all page. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a_kozubenko/eh25an74/7/)

Thank you

Comment: what result do you expect? do you need the max depth? or find the div with the max depth?

Comment: If your wondering what the issue is, it's because you only ever check the first child using `[0]`. You need to do the check for all children.

Comment: I expect 7

"do you need the max depth?" - yes

Comment: Yes, I know that I check just one, please help to check second child and return max nesting

Comment: Do you need to use recursion, or do you just think that would be the best way?

Comment: I need to use recursion

Comment: Do you want to find the maximum DOM nesting level of any elements, or just `div` elements?

Comment: DOM nesting level

Comment: Why is the answer 7, and not 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the body element itself for checking the elements and use a max variable to store the local max depth.

The recusion function need a `level` parameter, which is incremented for evey nested level. If no more children are found, `max` is adjusted, if necessary.

```js
function recursion (data, level) {
    var i;
    if (data.children.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.children.length; i++) {
            recursion(data.children[i], level + 1);
        }
    } else {
        if (level > max) {
            max = level;
        }
    }
}

var max = 0;

recursion(document.body, 0);
console.log(max);
```

```html
<div><div><div><div><div><div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div><div><div><div></div></div></div><div><div><div><div><div><div></div></div></div></div><div><div><div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Another approach without a level counter

```js
function getDepth(data) {
    return +data.children.length && (1 + Math.max.apply(Math, [].map.call(data.children, getDepth)));
}

console.log(getDepth(document.body));
```

```html
<div><div><div><div><div><div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div><div><div><div></div></div></div><div><div><div><div><div><div></div></div></div></div><div><div><div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: @torazaburo, a tree starts with one node, but here it's the body element, which is definitely not a `div` element.

Answer (score 4):

Split this task into two:

- Generic dom traversing
- Picking max depth

```js
// traverse root and its chilren using depth first search
const dfs = (root, iterator, depth = 0) => iterator(root, depth, [
  ...[].map.call(root.children, child => dfs(child, iterator, depth + 1))
])

// pick maximum depth
const maxDepth = (_, depth, children) =>
   children.length ? Math.max(...children) : depth

console.log(
  dfs(
    document.body,
    maxDepth
  )
)
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```